# Swallowed mucus/phlegm effect on feces/stool movement out of one's bowels

Tags: irritable-bowel-syndrome, diarrhea, stools

Lol, Sorry if this sounds disgusting.  :)

However, Swallowing my mucus/phlegm when I have a cold, fever, running nose, sore throat seems to make my improves feces/stool movement so that it quickly goes out of bowels.

Could someone please tell me if the aforementioned makes sense? If yes, could you please explain the science behind it?  Furthermore, is it beneficial or bad for one's health?